Docker Desktop not opening but Docker Desktop is running in the background
I am new to Docker. I tried to open Docker Desktop, I am pretty sure that an application should open up, but it didn't. Nothing happened and no output came to me, but when I open up task manager, it says that it is running:

Also I try to run this command, docker build buildenv -t glyphixos
and it says this error:
ERROR: error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Head "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.

I search it up and I have to be admin so I tried again, it did not work:
ERROR: request returned Internal Server Error for API route and version http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopLinuxEngine/_ping, check if the server supports the requested API version             

I search up again, I ask chatgpt and YouTube, chatgpt says that reinstall, I did that 3 times, I delete the directory of the docker at the program files and did the same thing, but nothing. I got to tell, when installing Docker, I check the first option which is install it on a wsl2 instead of hyperV and for the commands, I am using PowerShell, so is it that I have to use Docker on wsl2. And also, config and daemon.json is not here, so how can I fix it?

config is a folder and daemon.json is suppose to be in that folder build config folder isn't here
